# UIScrollView preview when scrolling

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll

I use `UIScrollview` to scroll vertically some images(their number is 100) and when i scroll Up/Down the next/previous image appear suddenly, and i don't want this i want a continuous effect. Can someone help to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code for the UIScrolView and how you load the images? Are you just adding 100 UIImageView subviews to the scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

Are your setting `pagingEnabled=YES;` ? 
Try setting 'pagingEnabled=NO;' while configuring your `UIScrollView`

Comment: hum, could you be more specific when you say "image appear suddenly" ?
In what method do you add your images as subviews of the scrollview ?